# gganimate transition_reveal() with geom_line() breaking on the final frame?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am trying to animate a line graph with multiple lines. It seems that there is an error with the gganimate package involving transition_reveal() that is causing the final frame to revert for all of the lines but one. This error is not present when not using gganimate. Here is the code:

```
df <- read.csv("test.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
anim <- ggplot(df, aes(Day, Accidents, group = State, color = State)) +
  geom_line() +
  transition_reveal(Day) +
  ease_aes('cubic-in-out')
jiff <- animate(anim, fps = 24, duration = 5, start_pause = 0, end_pause = 72, height = 4, width = 7, units = "in", res = 150)
jiff
```

Here is the dput of the dataframe:

```
structure(list(State = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), 
    Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    Accidents = c(5L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 8L, 4L, 10L, 2L, 
    4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Here is the output:

[image: ggplot ouput]

Regardless of the ending pause or how many values I have along the x-axis, the final frame will always look like this with only one line appearing as updated. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

UPDATE: Reverting the gganimate package from 1.0.8 to 1.0.7 did seem to do the trick after all.

Comment: I can't replicate your animation - I get the expected result, with persistence of the final frame at the end

Comment: @AllanCameron thanks for the response. Did you get the expected result even after including the end pause? I see another user posted an output without the end pause that has the same issue as mine, even though it is less evident without the end pause.

Comment: Using gganimate 1.0.7 I am getting the expected result, with persistence of the final frame.

Comment: Yes, exactly your code. It sounds like @JonSpring did too

Comment: I've updated, uninstalled, reinstalled both R and R studio. I tried downgrading my version of gganimate to 1.0.7 like @JonSpring mentioned. I've tried changing the renderer in gganimate. Nothing produces the expected result for me. Not sure why this could be, but it does not seem easily reproduceable.

Comment: @ddeann Not sure if you are still on SO, but I came across your qn after reporting the bug + proposed workarounds on GH. You may find [this](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/480) relevant.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in this line `start_pause = 0, end_pause = 72,`. Remove or adapt it:

```
anim <-  ggplot(df, aes(Day, Accidents, group= State, color = State)) +
  geom_line() +
  transition_reveal(Day) +
  ease_aes('cubic-in-out')
animate(anim, fps = 24, duration = 5,  
        height = 4, width = 7, units = "in", res = 150)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi TarJae,
Thanks for the response, but this output actually contains the same problem. I converted your gif output to an mp4 file and the final frame still does show the same as mine. It is less evident given the speed at which the frames are changing without the end pause, but I need to get the end pause for my animation.

Comment: @ddean you do not have to convert it to a mp4-file. Just reducing `fps` to 10 makes the problem obvious. I can confirm that this happens with `gganimate 1.0.8` but not with `1.0.7`