# How do I keep the labels displayed at the end of the animation?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

The problem with this code is that, as you will see, the last frame of the animation does not display all of the time series labels. I expect all of the labels to be present throughout, but only the "Zinc" label is present in the last frame.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

dt$Fecha2 <- as.Date(dt$Fecha, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

s <- ggplot(data = dt, aes(x = Fecha2, y = Indice, color = Metal, label = Metal)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_text(hjust = 1) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(as.Date("2020-03-16")), 
               linetype = "dashed", colour = "red", size = 1) +
   theme(legend.position = "none") +
   scale_y_log10(breaks = c(75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200)) +
   scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 months", date_labels = "%d-%b-%y") +
   transition_reveal(Fecha2)

animate(s, fps = 5, end_pause = 10)
```

[image: result]

The data used to produce my data frame `dt` can be found [on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1eQJRdA3njoX_VHOqOjpNlIpwJFnqZyEL).

Comment: This is a known issue in gganimate 1.0.8. Reverting to 1.0.7 solves the issue (see [gganimate transition_reveal() with geom_line() breaking on the final frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74971922/))